# Restricting access to a page if user isn't logged in with Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel

I've created a Dashboard page and i want it to be accessed only if an user is logged in. The login and register were made with the `php artisan make:auth` command. Any tips or ideas how to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just add the Auth middleware to your route

```
Route::get('dashboard', function () {
    //whatever
})->middleware('auth');
```

Make sure you have

`use Auth;` in your routes

Answer (score 0):

In Your web.php route, you can add

`Route::get('complaintSuggestion', function() {
    return view('patials.complaintSuggestion');
})->middleware('auth');`