# Disable sidebar menu in login page laravel

Tags: laravel

just want to ask a question, if I want to disable the sidebar menu page in my login page, how would I do that? In the first place, is it possible? If it is possible could you show me some example or even give me a link for me to reference to see how to do it. Because I still can access my data even without logging in through the sidebar so I want to disable it if possible. Thanks in advance

If you need me to show my code just ask, I will put it in asap.

app.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

   <title>@yield('title')</title>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ asset('css/title.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">


                    <!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#app-navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    @include('layouts.testSidebar')

                    <!-- Branding Image -->
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}" style="color: white">
                        @yield('title')
                    </a>
                </div>



                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        &nbsp;
                    </ul>


                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        @guest
                            <li><a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a></li>
                        @else
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" style="background-color:blue">
                                    <b style="color: white">{{ Auth::user()->name }}</b> <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>

                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color: blue">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                            onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();" style="background-color: blue">
                                            <b style="color: white">Logout</b>
                                        </a>

                                        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                                        </form>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        @endguest
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        @yield('content')
    </div>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am assuming you are using a master template and extending it for all page, So you can create a different template for logged in user and for the user who are not logged in, also you can provide middleware in your routes so that users cannot access pages which they can't

Comment: Yes, show your code otherwise we will assume

Comment: @arunkumar added code inside

Comment: @programmingArrow so your saying I duplicate it and put it inside login page while another is for user that are already logged in?

Comment: @Dkna you can see arun's answer, but your users can still visit the page by  typing in the url

Comment: @programmingArrow then what can i do to the url to prevent people from just typing the url in?

Comment: you can use middleware in your routes to prevent user's who are not logged in to visit the page check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43293167/7707434

Comment: @Dkna check the answer link

Comment: @programmingArrow thanks for the reference will take a look at it :)

Comment: Yup just saw it :)

Comment: @programmingArrow so just to confirm all i have to do is just use this? "->middleware('auth');"

Comment: @Dkna yes also include `use Auth;` at the top

Comment: @programmingArrow the default has already this,Auth::routes();. Does this do the same function? Because I tried it prevent user who are not logged in from visting the page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If u dont want to show the `Left Side Of Navbar` for the not logged in user try the below

```
@if(Auth::check())
    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        &nbsp;
    </ul>
@endif
```