# how to Implement logout functionality in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

without login If I give any URL's in the admin panel it is opening. How to solve it?

while login I am using,

```
$request->session()->put('userId', $user->userId);
```

In logout I am using,

```
$request->session()->forget('userId');
```

Route file,

```
Route::get('/addModule', function () {
    return view('addModule');
});
```

How can I redirect to login screen. while am calling any admin panel URL's.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restricting access to a page if user isn't logged in with Laravel 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43293052/restricting-access-to-a-page-if-user-isnt-logged-in-with-laravel-5-4)

Comment: Are you using the pre-built authentication in Laravel? Can you add your routes file?

Comment: I added my route file. No am not using the pre-bulit authentication

Answer (score 2):

Just write this code in routes.php

```
Route::get('logout', function(Request $request) {
    Auth::logout();
    return redirect('/login');
});
```

Remember to import `Auth` class